# adding んー to the end of a phrase (e.g. いつ帰ってくるんー？)

Tags: grammar, slang

A friend recently texted me 'いつ帰ってくるんー？'. I understand the question, but I don't understand why んー would be added to the end of the verb. Is this to add emphasis or emotional context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「いつ帰{かえ}ってくる**んー**？」

「ん」＝「の」

Around Kansai, it is common to end a question with a 「ん」 in colloquial speech. The 「ー」 should be for emphasis as you said.

Thus, a more "Standard" way to say the same thing would be:

> 「いつ帰ってくる**の～**？」

Kansai ladies have asked me questions such as:

「うちのこと、ホンマに好{す}きな**ん**？」 "Do you really like me?"

「最近{さいきん}めっちゃ回答{かいとう}したはるけど、ヒマな**ん**？」 "You've been answering a lotta questions lately.  Are you bored silly?"

Disclaimer: If your friend is **not** from around Kansai, please ignore this answer. I would have no idea what 「んー」 meant, then, in his/her dialect.  It is always helpful to tell us where the speaker is from when asking these questions.

Comment: Note that Tokyo people sometimes use it as a slang too. Some as faux-Kansai style and others don't even seem knowing it is.